# Google GCM: How to trigger token refresh flow?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Based on the new Google GCM implementation for Android, there is a new method that is called when a token is refreshed.

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Fetch updated Instance ID token and notify our app's server of any changes (if applicable).
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

I would like to ask if there is any way to trigger this flow in order to test the described functionality, since the documentation does not include any information about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Calling this method manually in unit tests of yout code?

Comment: The problem is not the actual calling of the method, but to understand the circumstances under which Google will trigger this process and be able to generate it.

Comment: From the doc here:https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceIDListenerService.html#onTokenRefresh() it says that:`Called when the system determines that the tokens need to be refreshed. And then the application should call `getToken()` and send the tokens to all application servers. Because it's google api for android not a native open source android sdk, so we cannot see the source code of that.

Comment: users complain that they don't receive push notifications. and tokens on backend are stale. I would like to test how token refresh work on android too.